# How can I use Compile to implement recurrence?

Tags: programming, recursion, compile

I am trying to make the code for the following recurrence. Here `wjoin[[i]]` is used for calling values from a data set and `a` is a parameter.

- How can I perform the following recurrence using `Compile`?
- How can I store the previous values of `gg[i]` to calculate `gg[i + 1]`?

I wrote the following code. But it is not working.

```
gg[1] = a - wjoin[[1]]
gg[2] = (a)*gg[1] - wjoin[[2]])
gg = Compile[{{r1, _Integer}}, 1/(a)*((1 + a )*gg[r1] - wjoin[[r1]])];
gg[3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this way?

```
getgg = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {w, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{g},
    g = Table[0., {Length[w]}];
    g[[1]] = a - w[[1]];
    g[[2]] = a g[[1]] - w[[2]];
    Do[
     g[[i]] = ((1. + a) g[[i - 1]] - w[[i]])/a,
     {i, 3, Length[w]}
     ];
    g
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

And then

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
w = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000];
gg = getgg[a, w];
```

Comment: ...Thank you for your prompt reply. But this code is not working.

Comment: Oh, it does work. The only problem is that quite large numbers appear during the calculations. Numbers that cannot be represented by machine precision numbers. But whether such large numbers appear or not does depend on the values of `a` and `w`. **Since you did not provide example values, I had to guess.**

Comment: It seems that I do have c compiler driver. Can you please help me to inform step by step in this case. I search for this. There are a few posts about this. I am really confused now.

Comment: I am also confused. What exactly is the problem? What error messages do you get? You may also try `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` instead if you don't have a working C compiler.

Comment: I added the picture with errors

Comment: Sir CompilationTarget -> "WVM" is working.....Thank you very much.

Comment: Aha. Then restart the kernel and use `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` instead. Or install a C compiler.

Comment: Henrik Schumacher sir, I have one more question regarding this coding you wrote above. 
"How to print each 100 th term (    g[[i]]) in the Do loop?"

Comment: Hi @ab, performancewise, the answer is "Don't do that." The reason is that for this: The compiled function would have to interact with the MathKernel _and_ the FrontEnd; that would undermine the purpose of `Compile`. Of, course, when the computation is over, you can simply read every 100-th entry with `g[[100;; ;; 100]]`.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  But if I want to calculate g[[i]] for 10 million terms then I need to monitor the program. If I can print g[[i]] for every 10000 terms then I can understand the progress of the program. How to do that?

Comment: You can simply write something like `If[Divisible[i, 10000], Print[i -> g[[i]]]]` into the loop.